# Domain of adjoint operator of negative Laplacian on an interval

Tags: operator-theory, adjoint-operators, differential-operators

Consider the negative Laplacian $-\Delta:=-\frac{d^2}{dx^2}$ on $L^2(0,1)$ with domain $D(-\Delta)=C_0^\infty(0,1)$, where $C_0^\infty(0,1)$ is the set of all smooth function with compact support on $(0,1)$:
    $$
  -\Delta:L^2(0,1)\supset C_0^\infty(0,1)\to L^2(0,1).
 $$
    I read that the adjoint operator $-\Delta^*$ has the domain $D(-\Delta^*)=H^2(0,1)$, but I never saw a thorough proof. Does anybody know a source where this case is discussed in detail?

Comment: Yes. In Joachim Weidmann's "Linear Operators in Hilbert Spaces, Part II". Look for minimal and maximal operator.

Comment: Thanks for the tip, I will look it up!

Answer (score 1):

Let

$T:=-\frac{d^2}{dx^2}$  on  $ L^2(0,1)$ such that
 $D(T)=C_0^\infty(0,1)$

let $\psi \in D(T^*)$ and $ \varphi \in D(T) $
$$\langle T \varphi ,\psi \rangle =   \langle  \varphi ,T^* \psi \rangle          $$
more clearlly

$$\langle T \varphi ,\psi \rangle = \int_{0}^{1}  -\frac{d^2 \varphi}{dx^2} \psi = \int_{0}^{1}  -\varphi \frac{d^2 \psi}{dx^2} =  \langle  \varphi ,T^* \psi \rangle$$

So from this we can get    $$ \frac{d^2 \psi}{dx^2} \in L^2(0,1) \Rightarrow  \psi \in H^2(0,1) \quad and \quad T^* \psi=-\frac{d^2 \psi}{dx^2}$$

inversely let $  \psi \in H^2(0,1) $  and $ \varphi \in D(T)$
 $$\langle T \varphi ,\psi \rangle = \int_{0}^{1}  -\frac{d^2 \varphi}{dx^2} \psi = \int_{0}^{1}  -\varphi \frac{d^2 \psi}{dx^2} =  \langle  \varphi ,T^* \psi \rangle$$ 
and from this we get  $ \psi \in D(T^*) , T^* \psi=-\frac{d^2 \psi}{dx^2}$

endded with $T^*=-\frac{d^2 \psi}{dx^2}$ and $ D(T^*)= H^2(0,1)$